# What's the correct way to calculate the average?

Tags: vb.net, average

This is a project I've been working on for a day or so and I can't seem to get it to work like I want it to. I know I need a counter and accumulator but I just can't figure out how to use it properly in calculating the average.

I've tried calculating the average by dividing the accumulator (maccum) by the MovingRating and it just returns an odd looking output that looks like an infinite symbol. So, I tried dividing the Counter by the MovingRating and still no luck.

```
Public Class Form1
    'declaring module level variables
    Dim maccum As Integer
    Dim mCount As Integer
    Dim totalRatings As Short
    Dim MovieRating As Short

    Private Sub btnRateIt_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRateIt.Click
        'Declaring variables
        Dim MovieDescription As String
        Dim MovieRating As Integer
        Dim strFirstSentence As String
        Dim strSecSentence As String
        Dim thankYou As String
        Dim ratingMovie As String
        Dim Stars As String

        'Input
        thankYou = "Thank you for rating this"
        ratingMovie = "movie with"
        Stars = "stars"

        'Process the data
        MovieDescription = UCase(txtMovieDscpt.Text)
        MovieRating = updwnStars.Value
        mCount = mCount + 1
        maccum = maccum + 1
        Label6.Text = maccum
        Label7.Text = MovieRating

        'Ouput
        strFirstSentence = thankYou & " " & MovieDescription
        strSecSentence = ratingMovie & " " & MovieRating & " " & Stars
        lblUserRating.Text = strFirstSentence
        lblRatingDisplay.Text = strSecSentence

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnAvgRating_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAvgRating.Click
        'Declaring variables
        Dim averageRating
        'Process the data
        averageRating = mCount / MovieRating
        'Output the processed data
        lblAvgRating.Text = averageRating.ToString
    End Sub
End Class
```

I expect the output of dividing the MovieRating  to be the average. I tried setting the movierating to 5 and adding 2 to the counter. So, when I try to get the average it just produces 5/2 = [ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sR9uM.png)

Comment: I suggest you use `Option Strict On` `Option Explicit On`, and make sure that you use a datatype which supports this kind of mathematical operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has lots of elements duplicated that I feel shouldn't (or doesn't) need to be there.

I think you were getting confused by the multiple declarations.

Have a look at this code, it is basically the same as yours, but with the duplicated bits removed

```
'declaring module level variables
Dim mCount As Integer
Dim totalRatings As Decimal

Private Sub btnRateIt_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRateIt.Click
    'Declaring variables
    Dim thankYou As String = "Thank you for rating this {0}"
    Dim ratingMovie As String = "movie with {0} stars"

    'Process the data
    mCount = mCount + 1
    totalRatings += updwnStars.Value

    Label6.Text = mCount.ToString()
    Label7.Text = updwnStars.Value.ToString()

    'Ouput
    lblUserRating.Text = String.Format(thankYou, UCase(txtMovieDscpt.Text))
    lblRatingDisplay.Text = String.Format(ratingMovie, updwnStars.Value)
End Sub

Private Sub btnAvgRating_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAvgRating.Click
    'Declaring variables
    Dim averageRating As Decimal

    'Process the data
    averageRating = totalRatings / mCount ' Average is calculated by Sum divided by the Count

    'Output the processed data
    lblAvgRating.Text = averageRating.ToString
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, I think you are correct. I realized this just a few minutes ago. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

First you're declaring MovieRating As Short, and in your routine you replace it with an Integer. My guess is that you calculation is using the Class Scope variable, not the Sub scoped value.

Also, please use Option Strict On

Comment: Yeah, I re looked at the code and realized the variables were being duplicated. Haha, I really need to DeskCheck a lot more! Thanks!